# Reduce image dimensions in python

Tags: python-3.x, image, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have in input an image with dimensions (28, 28, 3). I trained a keras model with several images with dimensions (28, 28, 1). I want 
   to check a single test image with this model, but every time I get a dimension error. How can I reduce original dimensions (28, 28, 3) to (28, 28, 1)?

```
test_image = image.load_img('test/number3.png' , target_size = (28, 28))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 1)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you would like to reduce dimensionality you can just choose one of the colour channels like this

```
one_channel_image = test_image[:,:,0]
```

or you could find use the mean across the colour channels

```
one_channel_image = np.mean(test_image, axis=2)
```

In my experience of ML image problems just taking one channel works fine.

If you need to increase dimensionality from (28, 28) to (28, 28, 1) you can use numpy.reshape

```
one_channel_image = test_image.reshape((28, 28, 1))
```

Comment: i don't get it waht are you just saying. i just only want to reshape my image through any library in python. shape of image is 28,28 i want to make it 28,28,1                      how can i do that.

Comment: That's not what you originally asked, you asked how to reduce dimensionality from (28,28,3) to (28,28,1). I have updated my answer to include your new question.